# How to perform conditional required validation ussing ozzo validation in golang?

Tags: validation, go

In Golang ozzo-validation, how can I validate a field which is dependent on another field ?

For example, if I have the following:

> ```
> return validation.ValidateStruct(&c,
>       validation.Field(&c.Name, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 20)),
>
>       validation.Field(&c.Gender, validation.In("Female", "Male")),
>
>       validation.Field(&c.Email, is.Email),
>
>       validation.Field(&c.Address),
> ```

How can I add a validation that the Address is required only if email is not empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library now supports conditional validation by the `validation.When` function.

Here is a code snipped which fits the validation you described.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        validation "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation" // or "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4" if "When" not found
)

type Entry struct {
        Name    string
        Gender  string
        Email   string
        Address string
}

func main() {
        v := func(e Entry) {
                fmt.Println(validation.ValidateStruct(&e,
                        validation.Field(&e.Name, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 20)),

                        // Note that if gender is "" and not required, validation returns no error.
                        validation.Field(&e.Gender, validation.Required, validation.In("Female", "Male")),

                        validation.Field(&e.Address, validation.When(e.Email != "", validation.Required.Error("Address is required if Email is set"))),
                ))
        }

        // All is fine for no Email.
        e := Entry{
                Name:   "My name is!",
                Gender: "Male",
        }
        v(e)

        // Validation fails for Email and no Address.
        e = Entry{
                Name:   "My name is!",
                Gender: "Male",
                Email:  "a@org.com",
        }
        v(e)
}
```

It outputs.

```
<nil>
Address: Address is required if Email is set.
```

The library documentation describes it as well: https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation#conditional-validation

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it in two ways-

- <s>Adding your own [custom rules](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation#creating-custom-rules)</s>
- Conditionally add `FieldRules` based on precondition-value i.e check `Email` while creating field rules then supply it to `validation.ValidateStruct`

For e.g.:

```
type Sample struct {
    Name    string
    Gender  string
    Email   string
    Address Address
}

type Address struct {
    // ... fields
}

func (s Sample) Validate() error {
    var fieldRules []*validation.FieldRules

    fieldRules = append(fieldRules, validation.Field(&s.Name, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 20)))
    fieldRules = append(fieldRules, validation.Field(&s.Gender, validation.In("Female", "Male")))
    fieldRules = append(fieldRules, validation.Field(&s.Email, is.Email))

    if len(strings.TrimSpace(s.Email)) > 0 {
        fieldRules = append(fieldRules, validation.Field(&s.Address, validation.Required))
        fieldRules = append(fieldRules, validation.Field(&s.Address))
    }

    return validation.ValidateStruct(&s, fieldRules...)
}
```

Comment: I already checked the custom rules section. Even if I write a custom rule, I need to use it with the 'validation.Validate("xyz", validation.By(checkAbc))' code which is again specific to the field xyz.

Comment: Okay, can you try second approach?

Comment: Sure, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @Crusaderpyro I have added a sample snippet.